# I have a folder with urls how can I call them? (python)

Tags: python, url, web-scraping

I have a folder with urls
I need to open each of the urls and pack their data.
I can go through them and parcel them already, but I wanted to know if there is a way to extract each of the URLs in that folder without doing it manually

Comment: Hi there, welcome to SO! Please help us help you by providing a [minimally reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, please check out [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Do you mean the URLs the html of a site, or are they URL strings in different files?

Comment: @golaloe1998 html :c